# PrestoSQL Why can't i divide an aggregating function inside a case statement?

Tags: sql, presto

I am getting null for some of the rows in Amazon Athena when the absolute difference is bigger than 20 percent.  I am not sure I understand the logic of why.  Can someone explain?

```
case
when gla_sqft = AreaBuilding then 0
when ((abs(AreaBuilding- gla_sqft)/gla_sqft) > 0.2) then 1 else null
end as percent_diff_logic
```

| AreaBuilding | gla_sqft | percent_diff | percent_diff_logic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1498 | 2100 | 0.2866666666666667 |  |

Comment: What's the data type on your columns?  AreaBuilding- gla_sqft)/gla_sqft.  Any chance you have nulls in either areabuilding or gla_sqft?

Comment: please can you add some data with the behaviour

Comment: AreaBuilding = int
gla_sqft = int

Comment: added some data!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are getting **null** because there are rows where (abs (AreaBuilding-gla_sqft) / gla_sqft) is less than or equal to 0.2. Performing a quick select query (SELECT ... WHERE ((abs (AreaBuilding-gla_sqft) / gla_sqft) <= 0.2)) should eliminate my assumption.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have standard case of [integer division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division), i.e. `602/2100` is equal to 0. Just multiply result of `abs` by `1.0` or cast it to double:

```sql
when ((abs(AreaBuilding- gla_sqft) * 1.0 /gla_sqft) > 0.2) then 1 else null
```

or

```sql
when ((cast(abs(AreaBuilding- gla_sqft) as double)/gla_sqft) > 0.2) then 1 else null
```